# Is it possible switch buffers in order of accessing but not opening?

Tags: buffers, jumplist

At first I am going try to explain you "order of opening". For example, if I'll open files in this order:

```
1_file.c
2_file.c
3_file.c
4_file.c
```

`:ls` command will give me:

```
:ls
  1      "1_file.c"                     line 1
  2      "2_file.c"                     line 1
  3 #    "3_file.c"                     line 1
  4 %a   "4_file.c"                     line 1
```

After if I'll jump into buffers `:b3`, `:b2`, `:b4`, then if I'll invoke `:bp` command then I would go in the buffer 3 or if i'll invoke (from buffer 4) `:bn` I would go in the buffer 1. So I'll jump between buffers in order of opening.

But I want to simple method to jump between files in "order of accessing", for example from previous example if I'll jump into buffers `:b3`, `:b2`, `:b4`. I want to jump back like: `buffer 2`, `buffer 3`, and after jump forward like `buffer 2`, `buffer 4`. I hope you guys understand what I mean. Is there native command in vim to achieve this?

I was searching on the Internet about this facility, but no luck. There are commands for jumping in history with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> but it cause jumping inside of same file too.

Answer (score 3):

My [EnhancedJumps plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2695) provides (among other variants) `<Leader><C-O>` and `<Leader><C-I>` commands that work like built-in `<C-O>` / `<C-I>`, but skip over jumps inside the same buffer.

I personally use the old [MruMenu plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=207) for buffer recall. It uses the menu (in GVIM), is file-based instead of showing the current buffers, and limits to N entries, though.

Comment: I was hacking a little with your plugin, it does pretty great stuff. Thank you! But actually I wanted more `:bp`, `:bn`-like behaviour, I mean cycling jumping between _current_ buffers. So I don't want jump onto already deleted buffers and want to jump on the first one if it was last buffer in the list of accessed buffers.

Comment: Well, you could modify my plugin / take some parts to build your own. Actually, I use a slightly different approach to the problem; see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a plugin on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2agj70/name_your_2_favorite_plugins_requirement_must_be/) which does exactly what you want: [bufsurf](https://github.com/ton/vim-bufsurf). From the readme:

> ... This plugin supplies the user with the commands :BufSurfForward
>   and :BufSurfBack to navigate buffers forwards and backwards according to the
>   navigation history. ...

Comment: Thanks! It's actually what I wanted. By the way I already found this facility in https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-buffergator plugin, but for me it's just overkill to use this plugin only for 2 commands, maybe if I need more comprehensive tool for bufer managment, but not now.

Comment: I've returned back to the buffergator, because bufsurf jumps to closed buffers.

Answer (score 0):

The [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) plugin's `buffer` source remembers the order of accessing. I just opened the files in the order you wrote, and the buffer-chooser window looks like this:

[image: unite buffer and list of buffers]

You can open the Unite with `:Unite buffer -direction=botright`, press `<Down><CR>` to go to the next buffer and `<Up><CR>` for the previous.

To make life simpler, here's the mappings to go to the older/newer buffer:

```
map  <C-Y>  :Unite buffer -direction=botright<CR><Up><CR>
map  <C-E>  :Unite buffer -direction=botright<CR><Down><CR>
```