# Is is possible to change the order of the argument list?

Tags: argument-list

When I have multiple files in the argument list, can I rearrange the order of the list?

For example

```
:args
 [A.md] B.md C.md D.md E.md F.md
```

is there a command/series of commands that gives me

```
:args
 [A.md] F.md C.md D.md E.md B.md
```

Why is ask I have a key binding for `:next` and `:prev` and it would be used full to move the files next to each other so I don't have to press the keybinding mutiple times.

Comment: For buffers, but seems relevant to your intended usage: [using Unite buffer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3202/1800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ touch {A,B,C,D,E,F}.md
$ vim *.md
:redir => current_args
:silent args
:redir END
:let current_args =  substitute(current_args, 'F', 'B', '')
:let current_args =  substitute(current_args, 'B', 'F', '')
:exe "args ".substitute(current_args, '[\n\r[\]]', '', 'g')
```

First you can use `:args` to retrieve the current list of arguments, and `:redir` to capture it to a variable. After you manipulate the variable contents, use `:args {arglist}` to set the modified arglist.

Note that the output of `:args` contains square brackets and newlines, which must be removed before it is used set the new arglist.

Comment: In case you do not want to use `:redir`, you can use something like `map(range(argc()), 'argv(v:val)')` to get the arglist as list.